# K8s service doesn't use autoscaled mongodb pods

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, service, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I am trying to **deploy mongodb with kubernetes** (gke more precisely). This database is used by a microservice which only needs to read in the database, so I thought of **deploying multiple pods with a mongodb docker in each of them**, so that the work is shared between them. To do that I created a mongodb image in which I uploaded my mongodb that I previously used with a single docker.

(Here is its Dockerfile, a single deployment of this image works in k8s so I guess that this may not be linked to the issue)

```
FROM mongo:latest
EXPOSE 27017
COPY /mdb/ /data/db
```

As the number of requests to the db varies during the day, I want to use **gke horizontal autoscaling for those "mongodb pods"**. **Autoscaling works as new pods are created** when the cpu utilization goes over the target I fixed in my horinzontal pod autoscaler, **but these new pods are not used** by the service I created for the deployment file used to deploy those pods, ***and that's my issue***.

Something strange to me is that the **new pods local IP addresses appear in my service endpoints**, and **when I delete the initial pod**, which is the only one working at that moment, **then the other pods created by the autoscaler get activated and so I finally get a performance improvement**. However, this is obviously not a solution to me, and moreover other pods created after I deleted the initial one don't get used either.

Here are the yamls files for my mongodb deployment and service :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: "$my_mongodb_image_in_which_I_have_my_db"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1800Mi"
            cpu: "3000m"
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: $IP_reserved_for_this_service
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 27017
```

And I am accessing those mongodb through pymongo, in programs that run in another pod in the same gke cluster:

```
def get_db(database: str):
    client = MongoClient(host="$IP_reserved_for_this_service",
                         port=80,
                         username="...",
                         password="...",
                         authSource="admin")
    return client.get_database(database)
```

This way of using and autoscaling mongodb might be weird and quite impractical but it's only a first model for me and I would like to make it work (or understand why it can't work).

Here are screenshots showing the behaviour of those pods:

[state 1: only the initial pod is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB21T.png)

[...but all ips appear in service endpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Ouu.png)

[state 2: initial pod deleted, the other work now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwHVd.png) (except the new one created by the autoscaler after the deletion)

[...and the endpoints are updated in the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXRN2.png) (the update is in the "+ 1 more ...", I checked in the google console)

I feel that the problem might come either from the configuration of my mongodb-service or from the way k8s or gke deals with mongodb images (anyway since I'm new to k8s I might be completely wrong on that too).

Any help or comment will be appreciated, and if you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There sticky connection in Kubernetes, a common and well-known feature of Kubernetes. Kubernetes doesn't balance packages, it's balancing connections. Once your app established a connection to a service, all requests to this service will through this connection. Kubernetes doesn't guarantee that the next one won't go via another connection.
Once of the option to solve - headless service https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services
Or service mesh, but it's too much for your case ))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned in my question, I want to access this service to connect to one of the MongoDB that I have deployed, i.e. to one of the pods deployed with my deployment file. However it seems that a headless service doesn't have either an external IP or a cluster IP. I tried to get the DNS server address with `nslookup mongodb-service` but it returns the error `server can't find mongodb-service: NXDOMAIN`, for which I haven't found an explanation or a solution in my case. Do you have an idea of where that comes from?

Comment: I found a way to get server address by running busybox `kubectl run temporary --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty` as mentioned here [Setup a Headless Service in Kubernetes](https://blog.knoldus.com/what-is-headless-service-setup-a-service-in-kubernetes/) , however using this address in MongoClient the same way I used the service IP before (either external or cluster IP, both worked since my python program runs in the same cluster)  doesn't work, and I get a `500 Internal Server Error`  when I send a request to my microservice. I probably don't get well enough what this server address is.

Comment: As I understand you need to communicate with mongo inside your cluster, why do you need external IP?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do. But since I want to have multiples mongodb, by having multiple pods, and I want to have a unique access to them (I don't mind to which mongodb my request is going since they are all the same), I am using a service for my deployment. But with a headless service I don't find any IP (external or internal) to send a request to this service.